How can I set a specific value on an array (matrix) of booleans per True/False without using loops in python?
I am trying to make two random generated matrices mat1 and mat2 with random integer values between 0, 255 and check which cells are equal.
and I know this much
import numpy as np

mat1 = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(1000,1000))
mat2 = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(1000,1000))
mat_compare = (mat1 == mat2)

I wanted to know how to set True cells to an integer value of 255 and False cells to 0 in another array type valuable.
I tried this much but it only detected 255 and 0 as booleans:
mat_compare[(mat1 == mat2)] = 255
mat_compare[(mat1 != mat2)] = 0

print(mat_compare)

and the results ended up as:
[[False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]
 ...
 [False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]]

and just to note again that I expect it to use no for loops at all. Thanks.

mat_compare has bool dtype. You can't change that by assigning numbers.

You might be looking for np.where. E.g.: mat_compare = np.where(mat1 == mat2, 255, 0) will do what you want.

You can simply run
mat_compare*255

which gives for example
array([[  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       ...,
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [255,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0]])


If specifically short 8-bit unsigned integer [0,255] is needed, then you could additionally convert the data type beforehand, e.g., mat_compare.astype(np.uint8)*255

there are many ways to do this task, using np.where, np.zeros, boolean matrices, and loops.
they all almost took very little time, except loops taking almost forty times more than others. and for the average time I took an average of 1000 tasks.
#Using np.where
mat_compare = np.where(mat1 == mat2, 255, 0) #Took about 0.017s

#Using np.zeros
mat_compare = np.zeros((1000, 1000))
mat_compare[mat1 == mat2] = 255 #Took about 0.015s

#Using boolean matrix
mat_compare = (mat1 == mat2) * 255 #Took about 0.016s

#Using for loops
mat_compare = np.zeros((1000, 1000))
for i in range(1000):
 for j in range(1000):
   if mat1[i][j] == mat2[i][j]:
     mat_compare[i][j] = 255 #Took 0.647s

